# web api 2 CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hey all I have this web service that I am trying to send some JSON to:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      cache: false,
      url: serviceURL + 'theQ',
      headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({ query: sqlCC, empImg: false }),
      success: function (data) {
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          app.employeeData = obj[0];
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.log('checker1' + xhr.responseText);
      }
});
```

And I installed CORS on my web api 2 function:

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Route("theQ")]
    public IHttpActionResult theQ(theQ.theQVars data)
    {
         .... code here.....
    }
```

But when I try executing that AJAX i get the following in CHROME:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev-zzzz/xxxx/Q/SELECT%20DI----D%20ASC/false?_=1454534694738. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://tst-zzzz.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Now why would I be getting this error if I specified the * to allow any?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting CORS wrong.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be present in the response of HTTP request on the  remote site not in the request.

Under certain conditions, browser also issues a preflight request - using OPTIONS method.

Response from preflight request should contain

various Access-Control headers

read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Hovewer your server should add this headers according on your settings of

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Have you enabled CORS support corectly?

Try calling enableCors() on your HttpConfiguration as documented [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```